# Numeric filter in Pentaho dashboard

Tags: pentaho

I am creating Pentaho dashboards on top of Pentaho analyzer reports. In the analyzer report I created two filters:
- One for a daterange
- One on top of a numeric value: value greather than a default value.

From the dashboard I want to be able to adapt the values of the filter. For a date range I do this by giving a name to the filter in the analyzer report, creating a promt in the dashboard and linking those contents.

My question is how to solve this for the numeric filter: there is no option to give a parameter name to the numeric filter in the analyzer report. And since the filter has no name, I can not access it from within the dashboard. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to create a prompt for a measure, as far as I know it's not possible. You still have the filter and it is editable in the report itself.

Comment: That's indeed what I am trying to do, but for me it makes sense to be able to do so: for example only showing results where a percentage is higher than ... And letting business users adapt this on the fly in the dashboard (they are not granted access to the analysis report). No workaround possible?

Comment: @WannesRosiers if you mesure is actually a plain value not an agregation then you can make it not a mesure but a column. If not, then no possible workarounds exist - it's like a difference between sql's 'where' and 'having'.

Comment: That is indeed a possibility for me, since it is a plain value. But in this way, I loose the option "greater than". For the filter I then can only choose select from a list or match a specific string.

Comment: @WannesRosiers yeep, I see. Then I don't see a way to configure it in Analyzer. You can try PIR. It has more flexibility, but lacks some functionality though